# Generate a symbolic interpolating polynomial in Scilab

Tags: scilab, polynomials

I've made a code to calculate the result of divided differences method and lagrange method by interpolating points. I would also like to build a polynomial using symbolic variables but how can I accomplish this?

```
function dividedDifferences(X,Y,x)
    ddMatrix = X'
    ddMatrix(:,2) = Y'
    for j=3:length(Y)+3
        for i=1:length(Y)+2-j
            ddMatrix(i,j) = (ddMatrix(i,j-1)-ddMatrix(i+1,j-1))/(ddMatrix(i,1)-ddMatrix(i+j-2,1))
        end
    end
    disp(ddMatrix)

    Px = 0
    for j=2:length(Y)+1
        prd = 1
        for i=1:j-2
            prd = prd * (x - ddMatrix(i,1))
        end
        Px = Px + ddMatrix(1,j)*prd
    end
    disp(Px)   
    endfunction

    function lagrange(X,Y,x)
    for i=1:length(Y)
        l(i)=1
        for j=1:length(Y)
            if i~=j
                l(i) = l(i)*(x-X(j))/(X(i)-X(j))
            end
        end
    end
    disp(l')

    L=0
    for i=1:length(Y)
        L = L+Y(i)*l(i)
    end
    disp(L)
endfunction

//example instance
X = [0 1 5 8]
Y = [0 1 8 16.4]
x = 7

dividedDifferences(X,Y,x)
lagrange(X,Y,x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a symbolic polynomial, initialize a symbolic variable with `x = poly(0,"x")` where x is the name of the variable to use in the polynomial. Then proceed to compute with it exactly as you did in the function `lagrange`. I essentially copied your function to `symboliclagrange` below, cutting out the numerical parameter and intermediate display:

```
function symboliclagrange(X,Y)
    x = poly(0,"x")
    for i=1:length(Y)
        l(i)=1
        for j=1:length(Y)
            if i~=j
                l(i) = l(i)*(x-X(j))/(X(i)-X(j))
            end
        end
    end
    L=0
    for i=1:length(Y)
        L = L+Y(i)*l(i)
    end
    disp(L)
endfunction
```

With your input `X = [0 1 5 8]`, `Y = [0 1 8 16.4]` the output is  0.85x+0.15x<sup>2</sup>, which is the correct interpolating polynomial.

Comment: Thanks! Could you just change the usage of x in `l(i)=` to `p`? The way it's written it gives `Undefined variable: x` at line 7.

Comment: Right, was a typo. Fixed

Comment: After I create that symbolic polynomial is there a method to solve it given a discrete `x`? `e.g.: x=7`

Comment: Yes: use `horner`. If `L` is a symbolic polynomial, then `horner(L, 7)` is its value at 7.